# Contact form 7 con plugin Material Design ralentiza la carga de la web

Tags: php, javascript, html, wordpress

He instalado material design para contact form 7 en mi web de wordpress. El problema es que ha empeorado considerablemente la puntuacion en el pageSpeed de google, ya que todos mis recursos tienen de 1 a 2kb de carga (excepto bootstrap que tiene 20kb). Pero Material design tiene 23kb .. y hace que empeore mucho la puntuacion. ¿Hay alguna forma de que material design consuma menos recursos? Alguna version .min o algo.?

Los creadores del plugin me han dicho que incluya el siguiente código, pero no me sirve de nada... sabeis si algo está mal escrito o se puede escribir de una forma mas eficiente?

```html
function graficoantonio_dequeue_cf7md() {
  if( !is_page( 'contacto' ) ) {    
      wp_dequeue_script( 'autosize' );
      wp_dequeue_script( 'cf7-material-design' );
      wp_dequeue_style( 'cf7md_roboto' );
      wp_dequeue_style( 'cf7-material-design' );
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'graficoantonio_dequeue_cf7md', 100 );
```

Comment: No te bases 100% en pageSpeed, intenta también con Gtmetrix, también puedes comprimir los archivos si son local, saludos

Comment: En Gtmetrix tampoco me sale al 100%, me aparecen errores similares al de google, es decir en movil 100% y en pc 70% ... requiere muchos recursos el plugin material design para contact form.. ¿hay alguna forma para que cargue solo en la pagina contacto ese plugin y no lo cargue al principio?

adjunto lo que me han dicho los creadores del plugin en la descripcion:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me ha respondido el soporte del plugin, dejo aqui el enlace de la respuesta:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/material-design-slows-considerably-the-loading-of-my-web/#post-11760268